# plugin to allow you to run cs6 indesign files in cs5?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, cs5, indesign-scripting

in our office we have multiple users all using different levels of creative suite, they include CS5, CS5.5 and CS6.

Most adobe files seem to work fine when switching between different CS versions, ie. i can open a CS6 PSD fine in CS5. But with indesign files they dont want to open.

I know about saving them as an indesign markup file and reopening them but from a work flow point of view this is quite tedious.

Does any one know of a plugin that i can install on CS5 & CS5.5 that will allow me to work in native CS6 Indesign files ? or a batch converter tool that would allow me to drag a load of CS6 id files and convert them to either CS5 files or indesign markup files ?

Comment: First Google Result: http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/batch_convert_cs3.html Have not tried myself.

Comment: Peter's scripts are phenomenal. He's a major asset to the InDesign community. The batch script works as advertised in all versions of ID I've tried it with.

Comment: I am facing this same issue with many files...I want to make sure that they will open correctly and wish that CS5.5 and CS6 were more compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InDesign files are very different from their other Adobe brethren. Each version brings key changes in how the page is structured. I'll leave it at that.

[Here's a discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4508300) that provides an answer to your question. Essentially, you export to IDML format and hope for the best.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I should elaborate a little. If you want to go back and forth and rely on something like IDML, just stick to features implemented in the older version. Deviating from that rule is the only way I've seen trouble arise. A few years ago, I used indx files frequently without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the only way to convert CS6 files into forms that can be opened in CS5, is by opening them in CS6 and saving them as CS4 files.

I've also found CS5 files automatically open in CS6, after installing a CS6 trial. Unless a user chooses to save these files as CS4 files, these files will be changed to and saved by default as CS6 files. This effectively forces conversion of CS5 files to CS6 files, so that a CS6 trial user is in the position of needing to purchase CS6 in order to continue working on their CS6 files when the trial expires.

(This probably was an unfortunate marketing move on Adobe's part, because the incompatibility could cause annoyance for trial users who might therefore turn away from purchasing the latest version. I like Adobe products, but considering their high cost they should really include better file compatibility.)